# Event Hub Source Connector throwing "Invalid Offset" error after changing event hub and consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-eventhub

I have an Event Hub Source Connector in my setup that was initially pointing to a single partition Event Hub within a namespace. Recently, we decided to migrate to a new Event Hub with an increased partition count within the same namespace. After making the necessary changes, I created a new consumer group for the new Event Hub.

However, I encountered an issue with one of my connect worker tasks that continuously failed with the following error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.AmqpException: The supplied offset '34361193416' is invalid. The last offset in the system is '357208'
```

Interestingly, the other tasks connecting to different partitions were running smoothly and processing data as expected. The problem seemed to be related to the old offset being used for partition zero in the new Event Hub. I tried modifying the error tolerance as well as including a poison pill handling mechanism by adding a DLQ topic but to no avail.

I tried looking for solutions on Microsoft and Confluent websites, but couldn't find any relevant information. Has anyone else encountered this behavior, and how can I resolve it to ensure data flows correctly without any loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the error encountered is related to the usage of an old offset from the previous Event Hub while trying to consume data from the new Event Hub, which resulted in an "Invalid Offset" exception.

When switched to the new Event Hub with increased partition count, the offsets associated with each partition also changed. However, the connector seemed to be stuck with the old offset for partition zero, causing the issue described above.

To resolve this problem, you need to reset the offsets for the connector. One way to do this is by changing the name parameter in the connector's configuration file to a new unique name. By doing this, the connector will reset its internal state, including the offsets, and start consuming data from the correct positions in the new Event Hub.

Make sure to follow these steps:

- Edit the connector configuration file (usually a JSON or properties file).
- Locate the name parameter in the configuration and change its value to a new unique name. For example, if it was initially set to "my-connector," you can change it to "my-connector-v2" or any other unique name.
- Restart the Event Hub Source Connector after saving the changes to the configuration file. Upon restart, the connector will begin consuming data from the new Event Hub using the correct offsets, and you should no longer encounter the "Invalid Offset" error. Data flow from partition zero should resume, and you should avoid any further data loss at the sink topic.

*Please note that this solution is based on practical experience and was not explicitly outlined in the official documentation of Microsoft and Confluent . However, by following these steps, I was able to successfully resolve the "Invalid Offset" error*